# How to recover WEP network key in WinXP?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, windows-registry, wep

I want to add another computer to my wireless network, but I do not remember the WEP encryption key. Windows XP has this key stored, I know this because it reconnects to the network each time I want, without needing the key entered again and again. Is it possible to recover this key (e.g. from the registry)?

I ask out of curiosity;I already solved my problem in another way.

Answer (score 1):

[WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) would do the trick - it'll usually give a hash, but it'll work just as well.